# Retrieving images uploaded by users in Django Templates

Tags: python, django

I understand there are multiple (if not 100s) of questions pertaining to my issue. After trying all, I am here finally to ask. I am able to upload the image and the image path in the model. Example of an image field from model:

```
<ImageFieldFile: static/image1_FzGpiKx.jpeg>
```

My static folder is right where the project and app folders are. In similar hierarchy. I have the following settings in my settings.py file:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/'
```

In my app level urls.py, here is what I have for rendering these images:

```
if settings.DEBUG:
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

After all this settings , my template shows the following as img src:

```
/static/image1_FzGpiKx.jpeg
```

Here is how I render in template:

```
<img src={{article.image.url}} />
```

Yet it just renders the typical broken image icon. Can someone help me here? Thank you!

Comment: how are you displaying in the template? please post that code too

Comment: I have added the code. Thanks!

Comment: do you have a STATIC_ROOT set to 'static' also?? its getting conflicted with MEDIA_ROOT, please change your MEDIA_ROOT to something else other than that

Comment: Nope I have a separate path for STATIC_ROOT. '/hello/'  and STATIC_URL = '/hello/'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
MEDIA_URL = '/static/'
```

use this in your settings file, and upload a new image and then check it

Comment: Specifically, what is the difference between my variable MEDIA_ROOT vs. what you suggested? Wouldn't mine also hit the base_dir implicitly?

Comment: no actually the one you gave was not getting the project path. thus it was looking for a directory starting with /static/ outside your project directory and django wont allow that